# Fb.ui post to wall

Tags: facebook, api, post

I am using the code below just as from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/ to post to a users wall. However the post does not appear on the wall. Is there something I'm missing?

```js
FB.ui({
    method: 'feed',
    link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
    picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
    name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
    caption: 'Reference Documentation',
    description: 'Using Dialogs to interact with people.'
}, function(response){});
```

I have the Javascript SDK `connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js` loaded. Do I have to add the following code?

```js
FB.init({
    appId: 'xxxXXxxx',
    status: true,
    cookie: true,
    xfbml: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons why it might not work. The information you provided is really not sufficient, so I'm just gonna go ahead and list a couple of reasons why it might not work:

- make sure you created an application on [Facebook developers] (https://developers.facebook.com/apps/), and have the Site URL correct along with the App Domains
- the "xxxXXxxx" in the `FB.init()` is the application ID generated while creating an app on Facebook.
- If you're trying on localhost, it will never work.

Finally, your code should look something like this:

```js
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId      : 'xxxXXXxxx', // App ID
            channelURL : '../../Vendor/channel.php', // Channel File
            status     : true, // check login status
            cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            oauth      : true, // enable OAuth 2.0
            xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
        });

    function postFeed(){

            FB.ui({method: 'feed',
        picture: 'https://www.example.com/img/fb-post.jpg',
        link: "http://www.example.com/",
        caption: "example.com",
        description: "a small description associated with your post",
            }, requestCallback);
    }


    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol 
    + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    }());
</script>
```

Comment: I only posted part of the code, I actually had everything right, cannot tell why the post was not working but I created a new app and changed the appId to that of the new app and it worked.